# When does a payable function "claim" or "take" the sent ETH?

Tags: solidity, security, payable

For a smart contract function to receive Ether, it is marked `payable`.

Is there a specific point in the execution of the code where the sent value is "claimed" or "taken" from the `msg.sender` by the contract?

If the payable function calls another internal function, can that function still "see" and check for the value sent in the call?

Does the answer have implications on how we should write interrelated functions securely when they deal with Ether values?

To illustrate: would the require check in `internalFunc()` pass or fail when `first()` is called with a non-zero value? (Sure you could check in the first() function, but just for illustration :) )

```
function first() public payable {
  _internalFunc();
}

function _internalFunc() internal {
  require(msg.value > 0, "send more than zero");
  //do something else
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`msg.value` can be accessed globally, so yes check will be performed. In other words, require check will fail if you do not pass non-zero value when you call `first()` function.